# Search records between two dates using Spring Data JPA native query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create an endpoint with Spring Data Jpa to enable users/client to find details of records using the date column from my table, however the records that are being fetched are only records from before the end date.

For example, I want records from between 18th - 20th, but the records that are fetched are records from 18th & 19th leaving out the records for 20th even though records for that date (20th) exists in the table. I need a way to retrieve the records of 18th and 19th along with that pertaining to the end date which is 20th in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Below are the approaches I have tried in my JPA repository using the JPA native query.

In the first approach, I used the native query BETWEEN but the records from the end date are not being fetched. This is the code snippet below:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_MASTER WHERE LAST_UPDATED BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate", nativeQuery = true)
List<PaymentMaster> getAllBetweenDates(@Param("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDate startDate,
                                       @Param("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDate endDate);
```

Below is another approach I tried that gave me the same results as described above and as the previous approach. Here I used the native query GREATER THAN/EQUAL TO AND LESS THAN/EQUAL TO but still didn't get the desired outcome. Here's the code snippet from the repository:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_MASTER WHERE LAST_UPDATED >= :startDate AND LAST_UPDATED <= :endDate", nativeQuery = true)
List<PaymentMaster> getAllBetweenDates(@Param("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDate startDate,
                                       @Param("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDate endDate);
```

Here is a code snippet from my controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/find/date-between")
public ResponseEntity<Object> findPaymentByDate(@RequestBody DateSearcherDto searcherDto) {
    List<PaymentMaster> paymentMasterList = paymentMasterRepository.getAllBetweenDates(searcherDto.getStartDate(), searcherDto.getEndDate());
    List<PaymentMasterDto> resultsDto = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Please check out my DateSearcher DTO whicd I created below.

```
package com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.dto;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
public class DateSearcherDto {

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

}
```

Please your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of LAST_UPDATED  ? LocalDate? Instance?

Comment: this is the last updated field the way I used it in my entity class below... thanks

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name="last_updated")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing date/time comparison, you have to put the lower bound to early morning and upper bound to late night. Also, update your query to take `LocalDateTime`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_MASTER WHERE LAST_UPDATED >= :startDate AND LAST_UPDATED <= :endDate", nativeQuery = true)
List<PaymentMaster> getAllBetweenDates(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```

In your service:

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(searcherDto.getStartDate(), LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0));
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(searcherDto.getEndDate(), LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));

paymentMasterRepository.getAllBetweenDates(start, end);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your solution but got an error as stated below:


JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2020-09-21": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020-09-21' could not be parsed at index 10;

Comment: (through reference chain: com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.dto.DateSearcherDto["startDate"])

I got the error in my Dto which I created solely for the startDate and endDate.. please check the question for the full DateSearcherDto class I created.

Comment: Can you update your DTO to have LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime . Also 'yyyy-MM-dd' is default format and you don't need to specify.

Comment: https://snippi.com/s/phne13a see this for working example

Comment: It is working perfectly now after I updated my dto to LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime... Thanks a million @gtiwari.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers of @gtiwari333 I modified my code and was able to get the desired outcome of fetching all the records including that of the end date. Below are the modifications for the sake of future readers.

My modified repository

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_MASTER WHERE LAST_UPDATED >= :startDate AND LAST_UPDATED <= :endDate", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PaymentMaster> getAllBetweenDates(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```

My modified controller

```
@PostMapping("/find/date-between")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findPaymentByDate(@RequestBody DateSearcherDto searcherDto) {

        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(searcherDto.getStartDate()), LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0));
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(searcherDto.getEndDate()), LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));

        List<PaymentMaster> paymentMasterList =
                paymentMasterRepository.getAllBetweenDates(start, end);
```

My DateSearcher Dto modifications:

```
package com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.dto;

import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
public class DateSearcherDto {

    private LocalDate startDate;

    private LocalDate endDate;

}
```

This was how I solved the problem. With these modifications, it worked like magic... Thanks.