# Spring Data JPA between date range return null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using native Query for the date between operators but it is returning null.
when I run this with static dates

```
@Query(value ="SELECT  a.name,m.title  from meetings m ,attendies a where m.id =a.m_aid and (start_time BETWEEN '2021-04-03 11:00:16' AND '2021-04-03 11:30:15' )",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findConflictMettinds( Date startTime, Date endTime );
```

able to get data, but when tried to return with dynamic values it returns null always.
below are the different methods I tried so far

```
@Query(value ="SELECT  a.name,m.title  from meetings m ,attendies a where m.id =a.m_aid and (m.start_time BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 )",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findConflictMettinds(@Param("startTime") Date startTime,@Param("endTime") Date endTime );                                          @Query(value ="SELECT  a.name,m.title  from meetings m ,attendies a where m.id =a.m_aid and (m.start_time BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime )",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findConflictMettinds(@Param("startTime") Date startTime,@Param("endTime") Date endTime );
```

Comment: Can you pass date parameters as string and use dateformatter to format dates YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez yes i have used ->  @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")

Comment: Then pass the string parameter to query, not date variable

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value ="SELECT  a.name,m.title  from meetings m ,attendies a where m.id =a.m_aid and (m.start_time > :startTime AND m.start_time <:endTime )",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findConflictMettinds(@Param("startTime") String startTime,@Param("endTime") String endTime );

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

repository.findConflictMettinds(dateFormatter.format(startTime), dateFormatter.format(endTime))
```

Also you don't have to use native query but if it is necessary then you can use with given example. You can also look for [Search records between two dates using Spring Data JPA native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015483/search-records-between-two-dates-using-spring-data-jpa-native-query)

Comment: @GurkanIllez tried with string but didn't for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass string of date as model attribute instead of as param

```
public List<Object[]> findConflictMettinds(@ModelAttribute("startTime") String startTime,@ModelAttribute("endTime") String endTime );
```